# Check every character of a string with guards [Haskell]

Tags: parsing, haskell, recursion, guard

i have a problem when i'm trying to use Haskell. I want to read a string of number and print various messages when i see characters.

```
import System.Environment
import System.Exit
import Data.List
import Control.Monad


test_parse:: [Char] -> IO ()
test_parse [] = putStrLn "\n"
test_parse (a:b:c:xs)
            | a == '1' && b == '2' && c == '3' = putStrLn ("True")
            | a == '2' && b == '3' && c == '4' = putStrLn ("False")
            | a == '4' && b == '5' && c == '6' = putStrLn ("maybe")
            | otherwise = test_parse (b:c:xs)

main = do
    let numbers = "123456"
    let loop = do
            goGlenn <- getLine
            test_parse numbers
            putStrLn goGlenn
            when (goGlenn /= "start") loop
    loop
    putStrLn "ok"
```

The problem is this. I would like to print "True\nFalse\nMaybe\n" But I print just "True\n". I know my problem is that when an action is made by the guards, it leaves the function. But I don’t see how to check the entire string without leaving '`test_parse`.

If anyone have a idea, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to check every suffix, regardless of the result on the prefix. One example:

```
-- output a string based on the first 3 characters of the input
classify :: String -> IO ()
classify xs = case take 3 xs of
                "123" -> putStrLn "True"
                "234" -> putStrLn "False"
                "456" -> putStrLn "maybe"
                otherwise -> return ()

-- call classify repeatedly on different suffixes of the input
test_parse :: String -> IO ()
test_parse [] = return ()
test_parse all@(_:xs) = do
    classify all
    test_parse xs
```

Comment: Okay, but if i use that, i can't choose if i want to put a \n after the print or not. Basically, it's working, but can we delete \n if we want?

Comment: You can have `classify` return a list of `String`s, rather than actually doing I/O, and let `test_parse` handle the actual output.

Answer (score 0):

To illustrate chepner's point about making `classify` return a list of `String`s rather than doing I/O:

```hs
import Data.List (tails)

classify :: String -> [String]
classify s = case take 3 s of
  "123" -> return "True"
  "234" -> return "False"
  "456" -> return "maybe"
  otherwise -> mempty

classifyAll :: String -> [String]
classifyAll s = tails s >>= classify

main :: IO ()
main = interact (unlines . classifyAll)
```

Running this,

```hs
$ stack ghc classify.hs
$ echo 123456 | ./classify
True
False
maybe
```

> I can't choose if i want to put a \n after the print or not.
>
> Basically, it's working, but can we delete \n if we want?

If you want to separate by something other than linebreak,

```hs
import Data.List (intercalate, tails)

...

main :: IO ()
main = interact ((++ "\n") . intercalate ", " . classifyAll)
```

Running this,

```hs
$ echo 123456 | ./classify
True, False, maybe
```

Splitting the code that parses and prints also makes your code more easily testable. E.g.

```hs
spec_classify :: Spec
spec_classify =
  describe "classify" $
    it "classifies 123, 234 and 456" $
      classifyAll "123456" `shouldBe` ["True", "False", "maybe"]
```

Testing this,

```hs
$ stack ghci classify.hs
> hspec spec_classify 

classify
  classifies 123, 234 and 456

Finished in 0.0005 seconds
1 example, 0 failures
```